# How to remove H1 title from CMS pages and category pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I want to add the H1 title along with the description in the description filed for CMS pages and category pages.

How can I remove the H1 title for these pages but keep the H1 title for products pages?

Comment: Vote up if the answer is correct

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For removing the tittle from the home page you can just add `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="false"/>` in your `cms_index_index.xml`. You can also use display true and false from where you want.

Comment: I have added this file to /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try inside your theme

Answer (score 2):

If you just go into the admin and go to content > pages and click edit on home page (or any page), there is a section called design where you can paste in the xml you want to execute. In this case, if you add: `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />`

It will remove the title from the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as still nobody's posted what to edit for category pages, the XML file to edit is in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`. The block to edit is pretty much the same as for CMS pages:

`<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="false">`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried in cms_index_index.xml something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing the title from the home page you can just add `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="false"/>` in `your cms_index_index.xml`. You can also use `display true` and `false` from where you want.

This thing works for me well now:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="cms_page"/>
    </referenceContainer>
  <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
</body>
```

place this code in `cms_page_view.cml`

Comment: yes dont forget to overwrite the file in your theme so that if in future if u upgrade it dont change

Comment: If you want to add something to your answer you can [edit] it instead of commenting

Answer (score -8):

Just add simple css

Get your page class in body and get your page name class with add css like

. Yourpagename .page_title h1 {display:none; }

Your problem is slove simple....

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But that wouldn't be good for the SEO :P